# Formatting strings android - how to show "%"

Tags: java, android

How can I show the symbol "%" in my formatting string? I could do only this: `<string name="progress">Current speed is %1$d %2$s</string>` and I got right output. Is there some way to show this symbol without second argument?

Comment: can you be more clear with your question

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape % with another %.

Example:

```
<string name="progress">Current speed is %d%%</string>
```